# How to Remove Desktop Overlay in elementary OS Freya

Tags: release-freya, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, desktop, gnome

I recently installed a program called nemo which is a file manager meant to replace the default GNOME files manager. I installed it using the tutorial and it said that if I wanted to remove the desktop overlay after using nemo, I would type the command  nemo --no-desktop. For some reason however whenever I log out and log back in I get a transparent desktop window which I can not remove by clicking the close button. Is there a command or anything that can fix this? If not then I am also not sure how to uninstall the nemo program in order to keep the GNOME files manager. I did not install through the software center.

I got the tutorial from [here](https://www.linux.com/learn/7-elementary-os-freya-tweaks-make-platform-even-better) (scroll down to where it shows nemo).

[image: desktop overlay error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To close that annoying desktop windows, type in terminal "**nemo --quit**" (without quotes)

And then to make sure this does not happen again, type in terminal:

"**gsettings set org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons false**" (without quotes)

The problem happens because when you start nemo file manager, it will attempt to manage your desktop (which you do not want, considering the Elementary OS Freya desktop cannot work with a third-party manager).